# Getting bad request error with alamofire JSON request

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

I have been converting this curl syntax

```
curl -L -X POST 'https://driver-vehicle-licensing.api.gov.uk/vehicleenquiry/v1/vehicles' \-H 'x-api-key: REPLACE WITH YOUR API KEY' \-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \-d '{"registrationNumber": "TE57VRN"}'
```

into Swift with Alamofire and have got this syntax

```
guard let url = URL(string: "https://driver-vehicle-licensing.api.gov.uk/vehicle-enquiry/v1/vehicles") else { return }

                    let headers : HTTPHeaders = [
                            "x-api-key": "mykey",
                            "Content-Type": "application/json"

                        ]

                    let params: Parameters = [
                            "registrationNumber" : "myreg"
                        ]

                    AF.request(url, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding(destination: .httpBody), headers: headers).responseJSON(completionHandler: { response in
                        print(response)
                    })
```

However, I have got the output

```
success({
errors =     (
            {
        code = ENQ103;
        detail = "Invalid format for field - vehicle registration number";
        status = 400;
        title = "Bad Request";
    }
);
```

Please could someone explain what I have done wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API expects the parameters to be sent as JSON, but you are sending as URL encoded.
Try using `JSONParameterEncoder.default` as the encoder instead of URL encoding.
Check Usage from the docs: [POST request with JSON Parameters](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#post-request-with-json-encoded-parameters)

```
let parameters: Parameters = [
                            "registrationNumber" : "myreg"
                        ]

AF.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoder: JSONParameterEncoder.default)
```

Comment: Try [String: String] instead of Parameters

Answer (score 0):

You have a working curl command, small (or big) tip: AlamoFire can print the request as a curl command!

In "one step":

```
AF.request(url, method: .post,
           parameters: params,
           encoding: URLEncoding(destination: .httpBody),
           headers: headers)
   .cURLDescription(calling: { curlCommand in
    print("curlCommand1: \(curlCommand)")
}).responseJSON(completionHandler: { response in
    print(response)
})
```

In "two steps", if you prefer to separate your calls and not chain them all:

```
let request = AF.request(url, method: .post,
                         parameters: params,
                         encoding: URLEncoding(destination: .httpBody),
                         headers: headers)
request.cURLDescription { curlCommand in
    print("curlCommand2: \(curlCommand)")
}

request.responseJSON(completionHandler: { response in
    print(response)
})
```

And you should have output:

```
curl -v \
    -X POST \
    -H "Accept-Encoding: br;q=1.0, gzip;q=0.9, deflate;q=0.8" \
    -H "User-Agent: Alamofired/1.0 (...; build:1; iOS 14.5.0) Alamofire/5.4.0" \
    -H "Accept-Language: en;q=1.0, fr-US;q=0.9" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -H "x-api-key: mykey" \
    -d "registrationNumber=myreg" \
    "https://driver-vehicle-licensing.api.gov.uk/vehicle-enquiry/v1/vehicles"
```

Now, if we compare with yours:

```
curl \ 
-L \
-X POST \
'https://driver-vehicle-licensing.api.gov.uk/vehicleenquiry/v1/vehicles' \
-H 'x-api-key: REPLACE WITH YOUR API KEY' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-d '{"registrationNumber": "TE57VRN"}'
```

I added some `\` to make it sill valid...

We shouldn't care about the order, the "Accept-Language", "User-Agent", "Accept-Encoding" headers that are added with Alamofire shouldn't be an issue. 
Try your command with no `-L` parameter maybe to check if it's "important" (if it's `--location`).
And then, the difference is with the `data` paramater (`-d`). Once is JSON, the other is URL encoded.

Then, let's see your code, and `URLEncoding(destination: .httpBody)`
might be the culprit. Using `JSONEncoding.default` instead will work.

Now, if you didn't have had the curl command, just by seeing your code, I spotted it. If you think about it:

You are saying there that you will provide the parameter in body following the JSON protocol.

```
let headers : HTTPHeaders = ["Content-Type": "application/json"]
```

And later, you used URL Encoding protocol.

```
URLEncoding(destination: .httpBody)
```

Doesn't make sense, right? You're contradicting yourself.